# Cypress can't run multiple test

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I have a weird behaviour in cypress lately

When i debug, the issue is that the test starts with this url `account.domain.com`
as the test goes on, it naturally move to `app.domain.com`.

All is good  for the first test.

The second one uses the same logic, start with `account.domain.com` ...

While the first one ended the test with the url `app.domain.com`, it seems that cypress is unable to load `account.domain.com` in the next test, it doesn't show any error, it just keep loading

Do you have any solution for this please ?

I'm using cucumber by the way